# Is Cl(f(A)) a subset of f(Cl(A))?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Suppose consider the space (R,d), where d is the absolute value metric, and f is a continuous function from R to R. Let A be a subset of R. Then is  Cl(f(A)) a subset of f(Cl(A))? Prove or provide counterexample.

If yes, can you extend in for any arbitrary metric spaces
I am very new to metric space and topology, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: About the inclusion, which is true for continuous maps"
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/a-map-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-for-every-set-the-image-of-closure-is-contai
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404901/f-is-continuous-at-a-iff-for-each-subset-a-of-x-with-a-in-bar-a-fa
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627329/prove-that-the-following-statements-are-equivalent

Comment: Here is a rather similar question: [Example of a continuous function s.t. $f(\overline{A}) \subsetneq \overline{f(A)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2686304). Other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2686304) might be of interst, too.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Consider $f=\arctan$, and $A=\mathbb{R}$.
You have $Cl(f(A))=\left[ -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, which is not a subset of $f(Cl(A))=\left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Of course, if the property does not hold in $\mathbb{R}$, it has not any chance to hold in a general metric space.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $f:X\to X$ be a function.

Under what condition do we have:$$\mathsf{Cl}(f(A))\subseteq f(\mathsf{Cl}(A))\text{ for every }A\subseteq X\tag1$$?

If $(1)$ is true then for a closed set $F$ we should have: $$\mathsf{Cl}(f(F))\subseteq f(\mathsf{Cl}(F))=f(F)$$showing that $f(F)$ is closed.

So $(1)$ implies that $f$ is a closed function.

Conversely if $f$ is a closed function then for every $A$ the set $f(\mathsf{Cl}(A))$ is a closed set with $f(A)\subseteq f(\mathsf{Cl}(A))$ so that consequently $\mathsf{Cl}(f(A))\subseteq f(\mathsf{Cl}(A))$.

Proved is now that $(1)$ is true if and only if $f$ is a closed function.